# How to invoke click.command with excluded arguments

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm having a wrapper command that invokes certain command in a loop with period(int value, minutes)

Wrapper command doesn't want to describe arguments of command that is going to be wrapped.

```
@click.group(name="wrapper-example")
def wrapper_cli():
    pass

@wrapper_cli.command("command")
@click.option("--path", type=str, help="example command arg")
def command(path):
    click.echo(path)


@wrapper_cli.command(
    "run",
    context_settings=dict(
        ignore_unknown_options=True,
        allow_extra_args=True,
    ),
)
@click.option("--period", type=int, help="minutes")
@click.pass_context
def run(ctx: click.Context, period):
    # no loop implementantion for clean example
    ctx.forward(command)
```

In this example with **forward()** I'll get an error, because **command()** doesn't know about **period** argument.

With **invoke()** method, I have to manually parse arguments from wrapper **click.Context.args** - list that contains raw and unrecognized args. ["--path", "path/"]

```
Context.args: List[str]
```

and pass it like:

```
ctx.invoke(command, **kwargs)
```

How could I exclude some variables from context to forward command without period argument.
Or how could I *clearly* parse **Context.args: List[str]**, that contains only extra, undefined for wrapper argument values and then use Context.invoke()?